# How can I show new modal or update the existed one after an input submit in Slack via API?

Tags: slack, slack-api

1. I need to show new modal after the submit of the previous one, but I need a trigger_id for it, and there is nothing about it after the submit.
2. I can use views.update API only instead, and I have a valid response, but the submit button closes the window and nothing happens on the client side after it all.
3. Slack doesn't show an input in modals without a submit button, so I can't use alternative buttons in the modal too, because a user anyway can click on the submit button and it will be closed.

Is it possible to show or update the modal after an input submit? For example, I need to take a data from the input and show it in the modal after, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could try updating the view using the `response_action`. That needs to happen within 3 seconds, but doesn't require a `trigger_id`. Docs for that are [here](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#updating_response).